# Typescript errors when using CustomEvents

Tags: typescript, events

**EDIT: [OnlineExample](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-shockley-gch7k)**

This works:

```
addEventListener("MyCustomEvent", function(e) {
    console.log(e.detail);
});
```

And this works:

```
class Foo
{
    constructor()
    {
        document.addEventListener("MyCustomEvent", this.Bar);
    }

    Bar = (e: CustomEvent): void =>
    {
        console.log(e.detail);
    }
}
```

But Typescript gives an error in both.

In the first example et gives an error when  I access e.detail, but if I do:

```
addEventListener("MyCustomEvent", function(e: CustomEvent) {
    console.log("Working!");
});
```

I get an "No overload matches this call" error.

In the second example I also get an "No overload matches this call" due to the fact that I call `this.Bar`.

Comment: Post a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Paul The code I've posted is a minimal reproducible example.
If I paste it into my editor (visual studio code) I get the two errors I mentioned.

Comment: I've done the same and am not seeing `"No overload matches this call"`.

Comment: @Paul Check the link I've just edited into the post. There it shows the errors.

Comment: You need to specify a target to attach the event to. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener